# Answer Listing by Most Upvotes

Tags: support, user-interface

IIRC, in the past, every page would sort solutions based on acceptance and then based on the number of upvotes.

Has that changed in the new schema?

Items seemed to be ranked using some unknown approach, for example, see [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Is this on purpose or this a bug? It was really nice in the past to see things in a ranked order as opposed to having to go through and find the better answers. What changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing changed. Answers are sorted "locally", in the sense that they are sorted by a chosen preference of the user.

There are three ways to sort questions: activity, oldest first, and votes. You might have changed it somewhere, and since this change is sticky, it affected every other question too.

[image]

Here you can see that "active" is selected. You can click on the others to have the answers sorted differently.

Comment: How silly of me to not have ever noticed that!! Thank you.